Anyone have a sample repo that use pallet-asset-conversion Im using the Substrate Solochain Template?
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk-solochain-template
This is the template I use.
https://crates.io/crates/pallet-asset-conversion
This is the pallet, I'm trying to add to the template
